# VisualGDB SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault with C++ dev for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu, visual-c++, raspberry-pi

I just purchased the VisualGDB extension for Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 with the student discount.
I have Ubuntu Mate installed and updated on my Raspberry Pi 3.  The Pi 3 firmware is updated.
Windows 10 on the laptop.
Any which way you write simple C/C++ code to print to the screen, I receive SIGSEGV segmentation fault.
[Screenshot of visual studio showing fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYHtN.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Even this simple code does it too.

I have scoured Stackoverflow and google.  Time to post.

Anyone have a clue as to what is happening and how to fix this?

Thanks Ladies and Guys.

Comment: In deep thought, perhaps this is a question for the VisualGDB developer....

Answer (score 0):

The tool chain was not compatible with the target system image.
You have to use EXACTLY that same SD card image as listed in the tool chain.
http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/

Per the developer for VisualGDB.[Answer to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4t30.jpg)

Comment: Basically I could not use Ubuntu Mate for Rpi (right now).  I had to use a 32 bit version of jessie (raspbian).